# JMeter - bzm Parallel Controller

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, blazemeter

Can someone please explain the "Limit max thread number" property for the bzm parallel controller plugin? When monitoring requests from the browser we can see there are some requests that happen in parallel. Is this property to be set to the number of requests observed occurring in parallel?

What would be the issue of not setting a limit, if the scenario is run as part of an Azure pipeline? Would it automatically determine the max number of requests that are to be executed in parallel?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Parallel Controller](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-controller) executes all it's children in parallel.

The limit is introduced to support browser-like behaviour, [the majority of modern browsers open up to 6 connections to a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser) in order to download embedded resources and execute AJAX calls.

So if you want your [JMeter test to behave more like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) and you're using Parallel Controller to mimic calls to embedded resources or AJAX requests you should set the limit to match the browser you're trying to simulate

[image]